# HTML Pattern, how to prevent number in name fields

Tags: html, forms, design-patterns

I'm building a form which will allow users to sign up. The technique that I used is the pattern attribute of HTML. Here is the code for the whole form.

```
<form id="signupForm" name="signupForm" action="https://www.google.com/" method="POST">

        <fieldset id="signup" title="User Infomation">
            <legend>User Infomation</legend>

            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label for="firstName">First Name *</label>
                    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" title="Please enter your first name" pattern="[A-Za-z]+" autofocus required placeholder="Please Enter Your First Name" />
                </li>

                <li>
                    <label for="lastName">Last Name *</label>
                    <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" title="Please enter your last name" pattern="[A-Za-z]+" autofocus required placeholder="Please Enter Your Last Name" />
                </li>

                <li>
                    <label for="username">Username *</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" title="Please enter your username" pattern="[A-Za-z1-9]+" autofocus required placeholder="Please Enter Your Username" />
                </li>

                <li>
                    <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" title="Please enter your email address" autofocus required autocomplete="off" placeholder="Please Enter Your Email Address" />
                </li>

                <li>
                    <label for="password">Password *</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" title="Please enter your password" autofocus placeholder="Please Enter Your Password"  />
                </li>

                <li>
                    <label for="passwordConf">Confirm Password *</label>
                    <input type="password" name="passwordConf" id="passwordConf"  autofocus title="Please confirm your password" placeholder="Please Confirm Your Password" />
                </li>

            </ul>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset id="other" class="hidden" title="Other Info">
            <legend>Other</legend>
            <ul>

                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="subscribe" name="subscribe" value="yes" />
                    <label for="subscribe">Subscribe to our mailing list?</label>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="agree" name="agree" value="yes" />
                    <label for="agree">I agree to the <a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a></label>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </fieldset>

        <input type="submit" value="Create new account" />
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" />

    </form>
```

When I try entering some number in this field (eg 11111111), I was able to submit the form with no problem. Is there any idea what I have doen wrong?

EDIT: I used the jquery validation plugin to validate entered fields. The script is as follow:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#signupForm").validate({
                "rules" : {
                    "password": {
                        "minlength" : 8,
                        "required" : true },
                        "passwordConf" : {
                            "equalTo" : "#password"}
                } //rules

        }); //validate

    }); //document ready
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a submit button? I'm pretty sure that you must have a submit button.

Comment: Yes I do, I only copied the code for the field I'm having problem with.

Comment: That means that your problem lies elsewhere. Please paste the entire form's code here. Also, try to make a http://jsfiddle.net example which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I edited the post, but I don't know how to make a demo.

Answer (score 0):

The form must have a submit button.

It works for me **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/3v9erkk6/)**.

```
<form action="whatever.php">
    <label for="firstName">First Name *</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" title="Please enter your first name" pattern="[A-Za-z]+" autofocus required placeholder="Please Enter Your First Name" />
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Instead of using the button tag, I used input tag with type="button". Is there any different?

Comment: Nothing functional. `<button>` is generally easier to style. (For example, you can't have pseudo-elements on an `<input>`). Your form will work the same either way.

Comment: I'm not sure, I used to use input tag since I don't know how to add the submit type to a button. I edited the post, please help me have a look to see if I did something wrong.